# Usando CakePHP, como gerar Pages editáveis?

Tags: php, cakephp, framework

Estou desenvolvendo um site usando o CakePHP, porém apesar de básico gostaria de saber a maneira correta de criar paginas como : Home, Contato, Sobre, pagina do usuário simples(logado com permissão 1), pagina do administrador(logado com a permissão 2),etc .
 Para isto gostaria de ter um template.ctp que incluiria views como header.ctp e footer.ctp
ou uma view que liste determinada Bean para o usuário simples(sem opções de alteração), outra que liste a Bean para o administrador, entre outras.
 Além disto estas paginas devem ter áreas editáveis, apenas para o administrador, para futuras manutenções de um usuário leigo.

Pensei em criar uma Bean chamada editableareas que possui todos os campos editáveis do site,
 os métodos da EditableAreasContrroler teria como view as paginas do site, porém não sei se é possível criar métodos com o nome home, contato, etc.. e mesmo se possível não sei se seria uma boa prática , pois não sei se a PagesControllers tem esta funcionalidade.

Gostaria também, se possível, saber oque fazer na seguinte situação:

Um site com 
1°tamplate que inclua view e determinadas partes
2°uma Home a qual mostra menu publico com (Home,Contato,Servicos), nesta home teria uma div editavel falando a respeito da empresa(esta div seria escrita pelo usuario).
Contato totalmente editável.
3°e Serviços que mostrariam uma lista da Bean servico, porém de uma maneira deferente de que se é mostrador para o administrador(sem opçoes de excluir e editar )

Comment: Recomendo que você veja essa dica no [Fórum Cakephp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cakephp-core/2hQd2p9dABY) a partir daí evolua suas dúvidas de acordo com que você vá desenvolvendo sua aplicação, afina de contas aqui nós tiraremos suas dúvidas e não faremos projeto para você

Comment: Eu acho que não soube me expressar, apenas queria recomendações de alguns padrões anteriores para não fazer "gambiarra", mas decidir fazer um Model EditableContent que possui seu nome e seu valor, cada pagina insere o conteudo pelo nome

Comment: Tudo o que você comentou é possível ser feito e pode ser visto na [**Documentação do Cakephp**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html)

Comment: Começe pelo tutorial de como montar seu primeiro blog, já é um grande passo
[Tutoriais & Exemplos](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) Estude sobre POO, pois sem esta base, se torna difícil implementar todos os recursos do [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o CMS [Croogo](http://croogo.org) para isso.

Poderá utilizar todos os recursos de permissão do CakePHP, como o ACL, pode utilizar os recursos de page e blog do Croogo e pode fazer seu próprio código CakePHP normalmente sem que haja nenhuma incompatibilidade.